# Group_by function not working with R markdown

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a pdf from an R markdown script which says this:

```
 test <- group_by(trials, SubjID)
 number <- summarise(test, nsubj=n())
 sum(number$nsubj != 12)
```

but when I click on Knitpdf I get the following error:

```
error in eval(expr,envir,enclos): could not find function "group_by" Calls: 
  <Anonymous>...handle->withCallingHandlers->withVisible->eval->eval Execution halted
```

I have `dplyr` installed and it works when I send the information to the console but not when I press `knitPDF`.

Comment: Canyoutrytoformatyourcodealittle?

Comment: Sorry I tried to paragraph it but the website would not let me submit it in that format. Thanks for editing it.

Comment: You need to load the `dplyr` package within the current or a previous `R` code chunk before using the `group_by` function. The code in an `Rmarkdown` document runs in its own `R` session, so it doesn't know about the packages you've loaded outside of the `Rmarkdown` document.

Comment: per @eipi10, add a `library(dplyr)` to the top of your code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add below library import at top in R markdown-

```
library(dplyr)
```